# Trouble in openEars to recognize letter

Tags: ios, openears

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I adjust OpenEars wrong recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614410/how-can-i-adjust-openears-wrong-recognition)

I used the OpenEars for my app to input word with alphabet. I just initial dictionary from "a" to "z" . But it had a bad recognition in recognize alphabet.

for example. I said "e" but it back me a letter"d",
and I said “d” it still back me a letter "d"

how can I deal with this problem.

Comment: is this a recurring problem? Speech recognition won't always be perfect as it requires clear annunciation

Comment: Look at Halle's last comment on your similar question. Utilizing alpha, bravo, types of words as a workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614410/how-can-i-adjust-openears-wrong-recognition/13615251#13615251